# AngularJS Directive is not being placed into DOM in correct place

Tags: angularjs

I had a "spinner" directive which is just a `<tr>` row in a table that displays a GIF "spinner" that is shown before API calls are completed.  All of a sudden, my directive stopped working properly and I have no idea why!

Here is my HTML template for the table

```
<table id="active-backups-table" class="backup-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Last Archived</th>
                        <th>Archive Size (GB)</th>
                        <th>Mailboxes</th>
                        <th>Items</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody ng-if="isLoading">
                    <sk-spinner></sk-spinner>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

And here is my directive

```
app.directive('skSpinner', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<tr class="spinner-wrap"><td colspan="6"><p class="spinner"></p></td></tr>'
    };
}]);
```

And finally this is what is rendered in the HTML

```
<tr class="spinner-wrap"><td colspan="6"><p class="spinner"></p></td></tr>
<table id="active-backups-table" class="backup-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customer</th>
                            <th>Last Archived</th>
                            <th>Archive Size (GB)</th>
                            <th>Mailboxes</th>
                            <th>Items</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody ng-if="isLoading">

                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

As you can see, the `<tr>` gets added outside of my `<table>` even though it should be replacing the directive tag inside the `<tbody>`... I have no idea why this would be occurring all of a sudden.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: can you replicate it in a plunker?

Comment: When you say "I have no idea why this would be occurring all of a sudden" do you mean that it worked before?

Comment: Yes, it did work before.. but I cannot figure out what I could have done. The only difference is I took all of my Angular JavaScript and I split them up into their own files.. ie `app.js, controllers.js, directives.js, etc`

Comment: Also, other directives are working totally fine, so it can't be that

Comment: is the table element here a part of the main html or inserted as a template by another route/directive? Can you post the whole html code here?

Comment: The table is just regular html. And I would rather not for disclosure reasons, but this page's HTML has not changed so It should not be that

Comment: it looks like an angularjs issue. What is the version of angular you are using? You may want to change you directive to use attribute or class instead of Element type. since <sk-spinner> is not a valid tag inside <tbody> angular could be not treating it in the right manner. Change it to <tr sk-spinner></tr> instead to work around this. I might not be able to answer why it isnt working.

Comment: @vaibinewbee I was able to reproduce http://jsbin.com/hotilumu/2/edit

Comment: Just use HTML inspector to see where the <tr> gets injected into the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified it to this http://jsbin.com/bozuziwo/1/edit and it works. As i mentioned i am not sure why it does not work that way but could be angular issue [see this: 1459](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459)

Comment: Oh interesting, so there must be an Angular issue. Thanks